# What made William Pitt beleive that it was in England's "interest of England to govern Ireland" when Ireland and England were unified?

Tags: 19th-century, england, ireland

William Pitt, the Prime Minister of Britain when the Union of Ireland and England was formed in 1801, said that it was in the "interest of England to govern Ireland". In what aspect of Ireland and its relationship with England was it in the interest of England to do so? What was the exact dynamic of the relationship between the countries @ that time? Was trade and profit a part of it? In what way?

Comment: I've fixed the title to attempt to give your question more focus, but the current revision is much too broad. Please edit your question to be more focused on a particular topic, as it sounds like a question taken right out of a history test.

Comment: I was actually asking about something I read in an article about Irish and English conflict that didn't give all the specifics. I also feel as if the question is more than focused, as it gives the context of William Pitt, a specific year to match the quotation, and it asks for 'key events'. Not an essay in response.

Comment: Well, you could probably point to the attempt of the French to land troops in Ireland to deflect English attentions in the wars they had going on as a reasonable interest.